Ubuntu 24.04 fails to start the graphical interface after installation and upgrade on an old iMac early 2009
I have tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 on an old iMac early 2009. The system on the USB installation key seems to work normally. After the installation from the usb key with the updates and rebooting the system, the login screen appears. After the login the graphical interface doesn't seem to work: the screen becomes grey and only the mouse cursor is visible.
~$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display


*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: C79 [GeForce 9400] [10DE:867]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: b1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=1920,1200
resources: irq:29 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff
ioport:1000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d301ffff

~$ lsb_release -a


No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Release: 24.04 Codename: noble

The system itself works normally and it is possible to connect through ssh.
I have tried to disable Wayland by modifying the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
I have tried to disable the gpu by adding "nomodeset" in the grub configuration.
Neither of those seems to help, after the login the screen becomes grey.
I haven't tried to install Nvidia drivers as the latest ones supporting this board does not seem to be usable with the current kernel.
How can I configure the system so that is works the same as launched from the USB key?
Any hints would be welcome.
Thank you for your help.

The issue does not seem to be related to the gpu driver but to gdm3. I haven't found the cause of the problem but switching from gdm3 to ligthdm solves it.
